# In sending the values to accdb for this form

Tags: c#

I used this code script but there is no error but db is not getting updated please help
the radio btn1,2,3 are a group for [year( II , III , IV)]
and radio btn 4,5 are in another group for [no_of_candidates (1 , 2)]
and chk box 4,5,6,7,8,9 are in another group. for [Events (paper present, quiz, debugging, ...)]
  AND THIS FORM IS FOR SYMPOSIUM REGISTRATION FOR MY DEPT.
please help

Coding:

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Registration(Name,Branch,College,Contact)VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "')", conn);
if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
{
    command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Registration SET Year='" + radioButton1.Text + "' WHERE  contact='" + textBox4.Text + "'", conn);
}
else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
{
    command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Registration SET Year='" + radioButton2.Text + "' WHERE  contact='" + textBox4.Text + "'", conn);
}
else if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
{
    command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Registration SET Year='" + radioButton3.Text + "' WHERE  contact='" + textBox4.Text + "'", conn);
}

if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
{
    command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Registration SET No_of_Candidates='" + radioButton4.Text + "' WHERE  contact='" + textBox4.Text + "'", conn);
}
else if (radioButton5.Checked == true)
{
    command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Registration SET No_of_Candidates='" + radioButton5.Text + "' WHERE  contact='" + textBox4.Text + "'", conn);
}

if (checkBox4.Checked == true)
{
    command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Registration SET Event='" + checkBox4.Text + "' WHERE  contact='" + textBox4.Text + "'", conn);
}
else if (checkBox5.Checked == true)
{
    command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Registration SET Event='" + checkBox5.Text + "' WHERE  contact='" + textBox4.Text + "'", conn);
}
else if (checkBox6.Checked == true)
{
    command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Registration SET Event='" + checkBox6.Text + "' WHERE  contact='" + textBox4.Text + "'", conn);
}
else if (checkBox7.Checked == true)
{
    command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Registration SET Event='" + checkBox7.Text + "' WHERE  contact='" + textBox4.Text + "'", conn);
}
else if (checkBox8.Checked == true)
{
    command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Registration SET Event='" + checkBox8.Text + "' WHERE  contact='" + textBox4.Text + "'", conn);
}
else if (checkBox9.Checked == true)
{
    command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Registration SET Event='" + checkBox9.Text + "' WHERE  contact='" + textBox4.Text + "'", conn);
}

myAdapptor.InsertCommand = command;
myAdapptor.SelectCommand = command;
command.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Did you paste the exact code? What is the meaning of those open/close braces without any condition?

Comment: i saw in a web site that those braces are for grouping but i also had group boxes before adding those "{}" withot any condition.
i too had that doubt but it showed no error either.

Comment: Many people have said this in the past but I feel I need to repeat it again. Used parameters in your SQL statements, you are exposing your database to huge risks of SQL injections!!!!!! I wish .NET would throw exceptions if things like this were used!

Comment: for your information i dint use sqldb conn at all i used oledb connection useing access.if any solution possible please reply.

Comment: Same principle applies, parameter can also be used with OleDb

Comment: what should i do?gv me a clear statement so that i can implement it.

Comment: please send me comment for sending the value of radiobuttons in any one group box to db. help...

Answer (score 0):

Use the sample below to update your code. Replace all dynamically created SQL with parameters

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection("YouConnectionString"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        // Not that all parameters are create with an @ at the front of the name
        command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Registration(Name, Branch, College, Contact)
                                VALUES (@THE_NAME, @THE_BRANCH, @THE_COLLEGE, @THE_CONTACT);";

        // Insert your parameters, change the OleDbType to what matches your field
        command.Parameters.Add("@THE_NAME", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@THE_BRANCH", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@THE_COLLEGE", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@THE_CONTACT", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
        var i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if(i <= 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to create record.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: k what about the radio buttons and check boxes? 
actually i feel trouble only with them.. plz help

Comment: What about them? you are using the text value to update the Event and No_of_Candidates field in your database. The sample above should help you do the same. Also note that I am not using an OleDbAdapter!

Comment: no, I use checkbox and radio btns for the update field.

Answer (score 0):

The UPDATE statement could be reduced to this lines.
You update always the same `Contact` but change the value for `Year, No_of_Candidates and Event` depending on the value of the checkboxes or radio buttons selected.
Thus, isolate this logic in appropriate functions that return the value to insert in the database.
Notice also that YEAR is a reserved keyword for Access so, square brackets are needed around it.

```
string sqlCommand = @"UPDATE Registration SET [Year]=?, No_of_Candidates=?, Event=?
                     WHERE  contact=?";
command = new OleDbCommand(sqlCommand, conn);
command.Parameters.Add("@year", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = GetYearValue();  //integer??
command.Parameters.Add("@noc", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = GetNumberCanditatesValue();  //integer?
command.Parameters.Add("@evt", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = GetEventValue();  
command.Parameters.Add("@cont", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text;
```

Now you have only to figure out how to write the GetXXXXXValue functions above. 
As a final note, `Year` and `No_of_Candidates` seems to be numeric fields not text fields. If this is the case then the functions should return the appropriate type (Int32) and the OleDbType should be changed to OleDbType.Integer

Comment: if I write a function as string as the return type it says not all parts of code return a value as error during coding.

Comment: Please if this is a new question, post a new question and accept here one answer if one has helped you.